# How to map users from Tenant 1 to Tenant 2 while migrating project between these tenants?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-migration-tools

I am using [Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://nkdagility.com/learn/azure-devops-migration-tools) to migrate my ADO Project A which is in Tenant A to Project B in Tenant B.

I have a similar set of users in both ADs but users in both these tenants have different email addresses.

I believe, when I run this migration, it will assign work items to placeholders as those users are not present in the target project(atleast with the same email address).

How can I overcome this?
I want to map these users when migrating to Project B so that those users are correctly mapped with their email addresses in Tenant B.

For example, User A in source project with email **a@a.com** should be mapped to User A in target project with email **a@xyz.com**.

Can I do that? If yes, then how?

(I can't use the approach of switching the Directory of my Project A to Tenant B as is suggested in the Docs of the tool)

Comment: Have you got a chance to check the answer? If you need more help, please share it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way, but still not nice, because you have to duplicate it for every field:

```
{
  "$type": "FieldValueMapConfig",
  "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
  "sourceField": "System.AssignedTo",
  "targetField": "System.AssignedTo",
  "valueMapping": {
    "Lastname, Firstname (Company)": "Firstname Lastname",
    "Lastname2, Firstname2 (Company)": "Firstname2 Lastname2"
  }
}
```

Here are the identity fields I know (please add more!):

```
"System.AssignedTo",
"System.ChangedBy",
"System.CreatedBy",
"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy",
"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy",
"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy"
```

There is a nice automated export to create a list of users in that format: [ExportUsersForMapping](https://nkdagility.com/learn/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/v1/Processors/ExportUsersForMapping/)

And an improvement is [planned](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/1776).

Comment: This! Just did a sample run and it works. 
The only drawback is the copying part and since we have so many members, the config becomes lengthy. But it does the job.
Also, there are many more identities I could find in fields section of Process but they seem to me less imp. 
For example, Activated by shows the name of the team member who changed the status of a work item to an In Progress category state.

Answer (score -1):

The template of Azure DevOps Migration Tools could map a@a.com to a@xyz.com.

You just need to edit the template:

```
 {
      "$type": "MultiValueConditionalMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceFieldsAndValues": {
        "Assigned To": "a@a.com",
        "Assigned To": "b@a.com"
      },
      "targetFieldsAndValues": {
        "Assigned To": "a@xyz.com",
        "Assigned To": "b@xyz.com"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I believe doing this, it would pick up the correct user IDs from target ADO and assign work items to them right?

Comment: Yes. Please make sure that the a@xyz.com is in the Organization (Project B).

Comment: This will not work since the "Assigned To" field does not contain an email address.